# How do I delete a blob that was created in my cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am running Great Expectations validations against .csv files I have stored in GCS buckets. When the validation runs it generates a set of validation results and data docs, which are stored in a different GCS bucket. I'd like to delete these files within the function that validates the data if the validation is successful to keep my bucket lean and easier to navigate within. I've worked on determining the necessary pieces of the blob name that is generated, which are attributes of the ValidationResultIdentifier within Great Expectations. However, when I use my delete_blob function I get an error that the blob does not exist. It looks like the function is inserting extra characters that are not part of my naming.

Here is my delete_blob function

```
def delete_blob(bucket_name: str, blob_name: str) -> None:
    """Deletes a blob from a bucket

    Args:
        bucket_name (str): the bucket where the blob is located
        blob_name (str): the blob to be deleted
    """
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.delete()
```

as well as the json name that I am generating:

```
    json_name = f'''
    {VALID_RESULTS}/{runName}/{adjTime}/{batch_id[0]}.json'''
```

Effectively I get a blob name of

```
validations/team/2022/1200/randomid.json
```

When I put my bucket name and this blob name into the delete blob function I get the following error:

```
NotFound: 404 DELETE https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/%0A%20%20%20%20validations%2Fteam%2F20220421-152311-raw-team-2022-04-21%2015%3A23%3A08.028947-data.csv%2F20220421T152311.141115Z%2Fbdbad345f0b11685beabf7f8a4e12a47.json?prettyPrint=false: No such object: bucket/
```

I have logged the bucket.name to the console and confirmed the bucket name comes across matching what I am trying to access to delete the blob. I've done the same with the blob name itself.

I've verified the service account that works on the data validations has full access to GCS, and in fact I delete the .csv file I am working on with this delete_blob function in another cloud function with no issues. I also know the bucket does exist since the function creates files within that bucket. I'm trying to figure out where the /o/%0A%20%20%20%20 portion of the error URL is coming from but can't seem to crack that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem come from your blob name. If you take the portion `%0A%20%20%20%20`, it means `new line followed by 4 space character`

So, exactly that:

```
    json_name = f'''
    {VALID_RESULTS}/{runName}/{adjTime}/{batch_id[0]}.json'''
```

Change the json_name like this should solve the problem

```
    json_name = f'{VALID_RESULTS}/{runName}/{adjTime}/{batch_id[0]}.json'
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much. I had split into the larger f string due to line length requirements, not thinking about the affect that would have on the actual variable.

Comment: Glad to hear that! However, I'm sometimes afraid of me when I'm able to read `%0A%20%20%20%20` without googling it!!